# How to commit and push job artifact to a specified directory in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

**Hi all,**

I have a 2 stage pipeline on *gitlab-ci.yml* file. The first job generates an artifact as an asd.asd file. The second stage uses this artifact. If pipeline starts from the first stage then the second one can use the first ones artifact. But in some cases I run only the second stage without running the first stage. So, I need to commit and push to the master the artifact of last successful running of the first stage. How can I do it in gitlab-ci.yml file?

```
stages:
  - first
  - second

job1:
  stage: first
  tags: 
    - asdasd
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - XYZ.sh
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    paths: 
     - folder1/asd.asd

#here the asd.asd artifact should be commited into folder1, how?

job2:
  stage: second
  tags: 
    - asdasd
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - run.sh
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    paths: 
     - folder1/asd.elf
```

Thanks,
M.Altay

Comment: Clarification: After getting the latest artifact. You need to commit it to the source code. Is this correct?

Comment: @TolisGerodimos, thank you for your reply. Exactly yes.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to put any build artifacts into any Git repository. Builds are to be *deployed*, not *committed*. But if you want to commit a build, you'll need to create a new repository to hold it, or clone an existing repository, and then `git add` and `git commit` as usual.

Comment: Thanks, @torek , actually I need to be able to run the second stage without running the first one. The second stage requires to artifact of the first one. Actually if there is any way of doing this, its better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I need to commit and push to the master the artifact of last
> successful running of the first stage

In order to solve this let's break it in to components.
To get the last successful execution of the stage in your case **first**, we will use the Gitlab API in combination with **jq**, to get the last successful pipeline as described in here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

We will use this API to get the **id** of the last successful pipeline for a specific project, with the following command

```
PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>"  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines?status=success" | jq '.[0].id')
```

Next, we will use the pipeline id to fetch the last successful job, from a specific stage in your case **first**. To achieve this we will use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

Command:

```
JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>"  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines/$PIPELINE_ID/jobs?scope=success" | jq '.[] | select(.stage=="first") | .id')
```

Fetct the artifact https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts
```

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
unzip artifacts.zip
```

Finally commit it with the commit API by passing to **content** property the path to unzipped file
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions

```
POST /projects/:id/repository/commits
```

```
curl -XPOST  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: access_token"  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/commits --form "branch=<target_branch>"  --form "commit_message=some commit message" --form "start_branch=master" --form "actions[][action]=update" --form "actions[][file_path]=folder1/asd.asd"  --form "actions[][content]=<path/to/the/unziped/file"
```